# Is there a way to make the scroll amount consistent across browsers when using the mouse wheel?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table inside a div with the CSS property overflow-y set to scroll.  When I scroll the table with the mouse wheel by one increment (i.e. one click of the mouse wheel) the table scrolls by different amounts in Firefox and Chrome.  However, if I click on the area below the scroll bar thumb, the table scrolls by the same amount in both browsers.  Here is an example that demonstrates this behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/rgxb6dz6/3/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <table id='table'>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 2px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 99%;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
}

th {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
}

#container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var tr = $('<tr>');
        var td = $('<td>' + i + '</td>');
        $(tr).append(td);
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            td = $('<td>' + Math.round(Math.random() * 10000) + '</td>');
            $(tr).append(td);
        }
        $('#table').append(tr);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to control how much the table scrolls when using the mouse wheel to make it consistent across browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, but it's not so easy and you'll need to get creative.

#### You will need to:

1. Listen to any events which triggers scroll (mousewheel, pageup, pagedown, keyboard arrows..)
2. Block the event from actually scrolling the content
3. Determine the scroll direction (it's not easy since you are blocking it so it's not so easy to detect the intention of the user)
4. If you know the intention of the user, you can scroll the area (body or whatever) by code, by a fixed amount of units (`px` for example)